# how can I pull a file from bitbucket

Tags: git, clone

I'm new to bitbucket and Ubuntu. I just created a project and a Java file on bitbucket. I was able to clone before adding the file. Once I added the file, I ran `git pull` - but ubuntu threw a fatal error saying `Not a git repository`.

I'm only one using this project. I want to get the file I created online, how can I pull it to my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized (using `git init`) a local Git repository into which this remote is supposed to be added?

You will get this error if your current working directory is not in your git repository. Before you pull, you should start by either `git init` or if you have clones a repo by git `clone <remote-url>`, you should change to the cloned repo by `cd <repository>`